# Restful Path Parameters in Spring MVC 3

Tags: java, spring, rest

Is it possible to: set a URI template in the mvc:view-controller element of the *-servlet.xml file or in a controller method and then use/get that path parameter *in a jsp*?

I understand that using @PathVariable in a controller method will give me access to the path parameter *in that controller method*. But how can I gain access to the path parameter *in the jsp*?

For example, is it possible to do something like:

***-servlet.xml file:**

```
<beans...>
<mvc:view-controller path="/home" view-name="home"/>
<mvc:view-controller path="/home/{error}" view-name="home"/>
</beans>
```

**jsp file:**

```
<c:if test="${not empty param['error']}">
<span class="error">You have an error...</span>
</c:if>
```

Answer (score 16):

If you want access to it in the jsp, return it as an attribute from the controller:

```
@RequestMapping("/home/{error}")
public void handleError(@PathVariable String error, ModelMap model) {
    //your regular stuff

    model.addAttribute("error", error);
}
```

-

```
<c:if test="${not empty error}">
<span class="error">You have an error...</span>
</c:if>
```

Comment: Note the wrong EL syntax, `${}` around `error` is not needed.

Comment: what if there is no controller? the setup i have is just the map between the request and the page(view) how would you treat parameterized url in such a situation. thanks

Answer (score 1):

The `Map` of resolved path variables is exposed as an attirubte with name specifed by `HandlerMapping.URI_TEMPLATE_VARIABLES_ATTRIBUTE`. So, the solution is

```
<c:if test="${not empty requestScope['org.springframework.web.servlet.HandlerMapping.uriTemplateVariables']['error']}">
```

But  accessing it this way is probably not a best idea, Affe's solution is cleaner.