# Retrieving request parameters from the URL with no parameter names

Tags: spring, jsp, servlets, url-rewriting, request

I have a URL which looks like: 
    [http://localhost:8080/resource/headline3-7]

In this URL

resource - Servlet

headline3-7 - Request parameter

At Servlet I am using the following code :

```
@WebServlet(name = "ArticleServlet", value = "/resource/*")
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws     ServletException, IOException {
     System.out.println("hiii"+ request.getQueryString());
}
```

I am trying to figure out how to get request parameters in this example ?

I can see the control is being transferred to the Servlet

Another thing that popped up is I am using the Spring frame work for the  Application , and I have a URLrewrite.xml ,  there I am trying to add the following rule that will help to get the ID  but it seems to be not working :

```
 <rule>
    <from>^/resource/([A-Z]+)$</from>
    <to>/resource/id=$1</to>

</rule>
```

Answer : 
Actually I used the URL pattern and the regular expression that Used was as follow :

```
 <rule>
    <from>^/resource-center/([a-z A-Z-0-9'-_]+)$</from>
    <to>/resource?id=$1</to>
 </rule>
```

this expression worked for me   and a the servlet I used use req.getparmeter function()

Comment: possible duplicate of [Restful Path Parameters in Spring MVC 3](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2951012/restful-path-parameters-in-spring-mvc-3)

Comment: Actually I used the URL pattern and the regular expression that Used was as follow :                                                                               <from>^/resource-center/([a-z A-Z-0-9'-_]+)$</from> <to>/resource?id=$1</to> </rule> – KAPIL PATIL 34 secs ago edit

Answer (score 0):

request.getQueryString() isn't going to work for you, since strictly speaking you don't have any query string - you're going to have to do a little bit of your own parsing, something like:

```
String param = null;
String[] paths = request.getPathInfo().split("/");
if (paths.length > 0) {
    param = paths[paths.length-1];
}
System.out.println(param);
```

Comment: Well That's what I thought of parsing the String , was curious to know if there is still an API that retrieves the parameters in this form of an URL . Thanks

Comment: you should have used the `@PathVariable` annotation.