# Having relative pretty URL

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, web, url-rewriting, seo

I have a requirement where we need to update the existing URLs with pattern as below

> somehost.com/appMain?id=x&subId=y&subsubId=z

to something more SEO friendly like

> somehost.com/appMain/USA/California/SomeLocalArea

or

> somehost.com/appMain/France/Paris/EffileTower

where,
id is USA/France

subId is California/Paris

subsubId is SomeLocalArea/EffileTower

So here mainly we want to have sort of folder structure in URL to have it more SEO friendly.
I am not very comfortable processing pure string based URLs in Java Controller and retrieve PK's from DB using strings and do further logic processing.

Just want to understand what would best possible design for handling such scenario.
Please let me know if anyone has good ideas to share for this problem.

Comment: Isn't this just about you using Query Params now and making the switch to Path Params. I understand that an extra level of lookup is required because you will not be using PKs in the url anymore. So what is the concern?

Comment: Yes my concern is splitting the URL each time to obtain each level of hierarchy i.e. id,subId and subID and then hitting the DB each time to get their individual PKs from String column. I wanted to understand if that is the only way to go about or there some better or more dynamic way of handling it using some existing good practice or even open source library which helps such kind of scenarios.

Comment: You don't need to split URLs or do any sort of string manipulation to retrieve the info from the url. Looks like you are using REST and your library (Jersey / REST Easy) will provide support for PathParam which does this work for you. Look here: http://www.nakov.com/blog/2009/07/15/jax-rs-path-pathparam-and-optional-parameters/

Comment: thanks for reply Saket. But i am just developing a web application using Spring MVC and URL format I gave would be the web application URLs.

Comment: This is how you can do it in Spring MVC: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2951227/150818

Comment: Thanks Saket..let me dig more into this.